# Storing json encoded string as a cookie with PHP

Tags: php, json, cookies

I am trying to store an array of URL parameters (format "utm_xxxx") as a cookie. I am converting the array into json string and creating the cookie but the cookie is not storing any value. The content of the cookie is "%5B%5D"
What is wrong with my code?

```
<?php
//Drop utm cookies
$utm_params_url = array();
    if(isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET)){
        foreach($_GET AS $k=>$v){
            if(preg_match("/^utm_[a-z0-9]+/i",$k)){
                $utm_params_url[$k] = $v;
            }
        }   
    }
setcookie('bm_utm_params1', json_encode($utm_params_url), time()+(86400*7), '/');
?>
```

Comment: Could you tell us what `$_GET` contains please.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking `var_dump($utm_params_url)` to see what got produced, if anything? And note that your foreach loop could simply be replaced with a single `preg_grep()` call...

Comment: Ok, so the URL is of the format domain/?utm_campaign=udm_display&utm_medium=ppv&utm_source=12345&utm_term=newgame&utm_content=sports.

Comment: Yes, I have done basic debugging by dumping $utm_params_url array and also json_encode string of the above array. Both the dumps look good. But when I store the cookie the value of the cookie only contains the square brackets [] aka  "%5B%5D"

Comment: I am not sure if it really matters but I am trying to do this in header.php file of wordpress. This code is right at the top of the header.php file